# Set tick labels with increment

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to set the tick labels on a plot (scatter 3D) and to make sure that they always have the same increment, no matter the values in my scatter data.

```
scat = ax.scatter(X, Y, C, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5, s=160, alpha=0.6)
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim(0)
```

Now, if I leave it like this, the `x` axis will have the tick labels 0, 2, 4, ..., 10, which is not what I want. I would like the tick labels to always be 1, 2, 3, ..., 9 (note that I don't want the 0 to show up). I want to set the `xlim` to 10 even if there is only data for `x = 3` for example. What is the best way to achieve this?

**Edit with `Locator`**

I tried using `Locator`, but I stil have the same problem:

```
scat = ax.scatter(X, Y, C, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.5, s=160, alpha=0.6)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.set_ylim(0)
```

I can correctly increment by 1, but I don't see how I can limit it from 1 to 9.

Comment: Look in to `Locators`

Comment: huh, thought that had an offset option....Despite my reservation, I think the _easiest_ solution here is to use @xndrme 's answer.  The way to do this the way I am suggesting is to write a new locater class.

Answer (score 1):

Use `set_xticks`:

```
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_xticks(range(1,10))
```

Comment: `set_xticks` is mildly dangerous.

Comment: @tcaswell what do you mean by mildly dangerous? I'm quite new to Python.

Comment: Is it ok to set `xlim` and `xticks` after the `ax.scatter` line? Or should it be set before?

Comment: I think there should not be any problem.

Comment: `set_xticks` replaces the `Locator` and `Formatter` instances with fixed versions so if you change the limits after using `set_xticks` to something outside of the range you marked, you will see no xticklabels (`set_xtick_labels` is much worse).  If you are using the figure interactively it will break displaying the cursor coordinates.